# Displaying List Item in CEWP on another Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, content-editor-web-part

I have a SharePoint with several calendars named for their store number, I also have a list named Store Addresses which has the store numbers and their addresses.

I am trying to display the address on the top of the calendar page along with the page name (e.g., Store 500 - 111 Main St). I figured out how to display the page name, but need help pulling in and displaying the address.

I am using JavaScript to achieve this.

Edit: With help from a coworker we created the following code. But when we run it, it comes up with the error alert.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var storeNumber = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
var fieldValue = "";
storeNumber = storeNumber.split("-")[0];

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',   function () {

    loadSharepointList();
});


function loadSharepointList() {


            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();


var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('storeAddresses');


            var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
            caml.set_viewXml(
     '<View><Query><Where><Eq>' +                                                                      
     '<FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value>'+storeNumber+'</Value>' +
     '</Eq></Where></Query></View>'); 


            var listItems = list.getItems(caml);
            context.load(listItems , 'Include(address)');
            context.executeQueryAsync(    

            Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
                           fieldValue = listItems.get_item('address');
                    }),


            Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
                                           alert('Error fetching data from Sharepoint!');       
            }));

document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = (storeNumber + "-" +  fieldValue);}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint rest api to get the list items in Store Addresses, then display the page name and address by jQuery.

Sample rest api demo from [this thread](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/).

```
function retriveListItem()  
{  

    $.ajax  
    ({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('companyInfo')/items?$select=Company,Industry",  
        type: type,  
        data: data,  
        headers:  
        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "IF-MATCH": "*",  
            "X-HTTP-Method": null  
        },  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(data)   
        {  
            $("#ResultDiv").empty();  
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)   
            {  
                var item = data.d.results[i];  
                $("#ResultDiv").append(item.Company + "\t" + item.Industry + "<br/>");  
            }  
        },  
        error: function(data)  
        {  
            $("#ResultDiv").empty().text(data.responseJSON.error);  
        }  
    });  
}
```